# How can variadic template represent specific struct constructor`s parameters in IntelliSense

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, variadic-templates

I'd like to see intellisense about constructors like make_unique. I looked at make_unique and tried following (I could be wrong) but it didn't work.

The following code shows what I want to do, not the problem.

```
#include <memory>

struct Struct
{
    Struct(int a)
    {

    }
};

template <typename Type, typename... Args>
Type* make_struct(Args&&... args)
{
    return new Type(std::forward<Type>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    // std::make_unique can see the constructor in intelliSense.
    std::unique_ptr<Struct> a = std::make_unique<Struct>(3); 

    // make_struct can`t see the constructor in intelliSense.
    std::unique_ptr<Struct> c(make_struct<Struct>(3));
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the problem with `make_struct`? apart from not using forwarding references that is

Comment: You probably need to start with a simpler exercise. There's several things going on, and it's not obvious where to start the explanation.

Comment: `I want the variadic template to appear as constructor parameters` You want to write `template<typename A, template <typename... Args> class B> Struct (B<A> arg);`? Here `B` is a variadic template that appears in constructor of `Struct`. Could you explain why are you making `make_unique2` and why is it inside `std` and how is related to your question?

Comment: *"// make_struct can't see the constructor in intelliSense."* What do you mean? The line following this line compiles just fine and doesn't show any issues in VS. Which constructor are you talking about btw? Constructor 3/7 showing up in the autocompletion for `std::unique_ptr<Struct>` is `std::unique_ptr<Struct>::unique_ptr(Struct*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `make_unique<Struct>(...` (i.e. passing Struct as a template parameter) but `make_struct` without any template parameters. The second can't deduce the type of the object you're trying to make.

Either drop the extra template parameter i.e.

```
template <typename... Args>
Struct* make_struct(Args&&... args)
{
    return new Struct(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

or pass the "non-deducible" parameter to the call, i.e.

```
make_struct<Struct>(...); // Doesn't really make sense since the very name
                          // Implies you're making a struct.
```

Comment: Sorry. It still doesn`t work.

Comment: @김범무 I see you edited the title to include "in intellisence"

Comment: I'm still not used to asking good questions. sorry.

Comment: @김범무 Visual studio IntelliSense has dedicate hooks for standard library functions. If this is solely about intelliSense you might not be able to beat what comes bundled with the vendor

Comment: Does that mean It can't just use code to make it visible in intellisense?

Comment: @김범무 It means that the "in-house" code is written in the best possible way to facilitate the fuzzy parser that provides intellisense, something you might not be doing. E.g. even the way you write comments can affect what intellisense shows, the inclusion order, macro expansion etc.

Comment: @김범무 check here how to [best configure a C++ project for intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-intellisense-configuration?view=vs-2022). Note that VS uses a dedicated compiler to perform IntelliSense which means there can be a mismatch between what the compiler ends up doing and what IntelliSense informs you about.